# Showing the Employees included in a specified salary range range on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

I am trying to show the employees in my database on a datagridview. but I want to show only specified employees by the salary range so what will be shown in the datagridview is the employees included in that salary range. Like showing all the employees in a salary range between 5000$ and 20000$ on the datagridview.
That is the code I tried but It shows me all the employees instead of showing the ones included in the range

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\himaf\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\برنامج الموظفين\برنامج الموظفين\EmployeesProgram1.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from EmployeesInfo", connection);
        OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand("select * from EmployeesInfo", connection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (int.Parse(reader[2].ToString()) >= int.Parse(txtFrom.Text) && int.Parse(reader[2].ToString()) <= int.Parse(txtTo.Text))
            {
                table.Load(command2.ExecuteReader());
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: Your `select` statement gets all records regardless of any other logic. And, you **do not** want to assign the datasource in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataReader doesn't work like that. What you are doing is checking each row if it has a salary within the given range. If any row has that, you load the whole dataset into your datagrid. And you load the dataset for every row that has a salary within the range.

I would suggest you read up on datareader here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Other than that I would also suggest that you use your sql-engine to filter out the rows you don't want. Something like

```
select * from EmployeesInfo where salary => @lowerbound and salary <= @upperbound
```